# React Native Expo App Crash Just in iOS review, not locally or on Test Flight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I built an iOS app using react native and expo.
It and working locally (on Windows) and on Test Flight on both iPad /iPhone (iOS v17), but the Apple App Store rejects the app because of a crash.
I've tried adding PersistGate for a fallback component, and reinstalling react navigation, as well as running `npx expo start --no-dev --clear` and `npx expo start --no-dev --minify` to identify issues.

Does anyone notice something from my package.json or the crash report?

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fantasymobileapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.15",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "cli-cursor": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.14",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "shadow-utils": "^2.0.1",
    "yahoo-fantasy": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Crash Report Snippet:

```
{
  "lastExceptionBacktrace": [
    {
      "imageOffset": 972256,
      "symbol": "__exceptionPreprocess",
      "symbolLocation": 164,
      "imageIndex": 4
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 179200,
      "symbol": "objc_exception_throw",
      "symbolLocation": 60,
      "imageIndex": 13
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 1516104,
      "symbol": "-[NSException init]",
      "symbolLocation": 0,
      "imageIndex": 4
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 461064,
      "imageIndex": 2
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 456144,
      "imageIndex": 2
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 455180,
      "imageIndex": 2
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 260932,
      "imageIndex": 2
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 9896,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_call_block_and_release",
      "symbolLocation": 32,
      "imageIndex": 14
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 17152,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_client_callout",
      "symbolLocation": 20,
      "imageIndex": 14
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 47252,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_lane_serial_drain",
      "symbolLocation": 748,
      "imageIndex": 14
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 50116,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_lane_invoke",
      "symbolLocation": 380,
      "imageIndex": 14
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 94212,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh",
      "symbolLocation": 288,
      "imageIndex": 14
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 92280,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread",
      "symbolLocation": 404,
      "imageIndex": 14
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 6500,
      "symbol": "_pthread_wqthread",
      "symbolLocation": 288,
      "imageIndex": 11
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 6660,
      "symbol": "start_wqthread",
      "symbolLocation": 8,
      "imageIndex": 11
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks so much in advance